# Visual Studio 2022 for Mac automatically adds info.plist to iOS project with Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac

When I open an existing Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio 2022 For Mac it automatically generates an empty Info.plist with a reference in the iOS project.

This wasn't the case with the 2019 version of Visual Studio for Mac. Is there a possibility to disable this annoying behaviour?

Cheers

Comment: Just exclude it from the project, Quick question though why no info.plist?

Comment: Hi @FreakyAli, because the info.plist is completely empty so why should it be included? Besides that, this behaviour started after updating to 2022 from 2019. For me it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What's the version of your visual studio?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Visual Studio for Mac 2022 (version 17.3.5 (build 0).

Comment: You can try to check file `cproj` to find out if some new items have been added.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT That's the problem I asked about in this ticket ;)